# How to get Palm Oil?

Tags: oil, breakfast

I am trying to make my own Nutella from raw ingredients. I have tried many recipes and eventually bought a wet grinder to make smooth hazelnut paste. Then I bought criollo couverture chocolate and I was able to make the most amazing hazelnut-cocoa-spread. But it has a flaw, it is too soft and it becomes almost liquid when spread on a fresh toasted bread slice.

So I tried to replace some of the oil I used with cacao butter and it was better. Then I used coco oil for the rest and it was perfect. But again this recipe have a big issue. coco oil and cacao butter are both worth than palm oil in terms of saturated oil.

Now I am trying to buy some "palm oil" but this looks like mission impossible. I either find cosmetic products, or articles about deforestation. When a find an interesting shop, it sells liquid reddish palm oil, not the white buttery paste I saw on *how is it made*.

Where can I find `palm oil` and how should I call it?

Comment: I don’t quite understand what you mean by “coco oil and cacao butter are both worth than palm oil in terms of saturated oil”? Do you mean they contain more saturated fats? Because in that case I’d just not bother: I doubt the change will make your homemade nutella “healthy” by any reasonable standard.

Comment: Look at the Trans and saturated fats. The best of three is the palm oil, the worse is the coconut one.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, unhydrogenated vegetable fats shouldn’t really contain trans-fats. Coconut and cocoa oils will contain saturated fats, which is what makes them more solid, the thing you want in the first place. Palm kernel oil production is also notoriously bad for the environment; I suppose you could get organic. Which is available on Amazon, so I’m not sure what the mystery is... Try a “price comparison” website for your country which will search several webshops that work locally, or eBay for cheaper shipping

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your description of being more solid, I think you might actually want palm shortening.  Shortening is 100% fat and doesn't contain any water, making it more solid at room temperature.

Palm shortening does look a little closer to butter
[image: Palm shortening]

A quick google search shows that Amazon does sell [palm shortening](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B008YJ000E).

Answer (score 2):

What you are missing are the terms "RBD" and "food grade". RBD means "refined, bleached, deodorized" - palm oil is red and smelly when pressed, so this process changes it to the white mass you want.

Palm oil is also frequently fractioned into palm olein and palm stearine, the stearine being harder. But I can't tell you which one is used in the production of Nutella, or if they are using the full mixture or a further-processed product like the shortening Alex linked. You will have to experiment there.